# Video editing software to fill a long video in short time

Tags: video, video-editing

I am looking for a open-source or free-ware software for Windows [XP] which can

fit a long video in a short time. If the video has a running time of 2 minutes it can be re-sized to fill in 1 minute or 3 minutes time.

I don't want to cut the video, just want to make it play faster or slower.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Windows movie Maker will do this. If you have Windows XP SP2 or SP3, it should already be available on your machine. If you do not see it on any menu, Click Start -> Run, and then type 'moviemk' and hit enter or click OK. Should pop right up.